# Pandas: converting timezone-aware datetime objects to a common timezone

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a Pandas dataframe `df` retrieved from an API call that looks *similar* to the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'opened_time':['2021-03-12T13:45:47.000-0500', '2021-03-11T17:12:23.000-0600', '2021-03-11T10:25:09.000-0600', '2021-03-10T15:08:34.000-0500', '2021-03-09T08:15:22.000-0600'],
                   'closed_time': ['2021-03-15T17:08:14.000-0600', '2021-03-15T18:56:57.000-0500', '2021-03-12T15:32:22.000-0600', '2021-03-12T11:08:20.000-0500', '2021-03-11T09:19:08.000-0500']})


opened_time                      closed_time
2021-03-12T13:45:47.000-0500     2021-03-15T17:08:14.000-0600
2021-03-11T17:12:23.000-0600     2021-03-15T18:56:57.000-0500
2021-03-11T10:25:09.000-0600     2021-03-12T15:32:22.000-0600
2021-03-10T15:08:34.000-0500     2021-03-12T11:08:20.000-0500
2021-03-09T08:15:22.000-0600     2021-03-11T09:19:08.000-0500
```

Calling `df.dtypes` shows:

```
opened_time     object
closed_time     object
dtype:          object
```

Calling `df['opened_time].unique()` shows:

```
array([datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 12, 13, 45, 47, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000)),
       datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 11, 17, 12, 23, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -21600)),
       datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 11, 10, 25, 09, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -21600)),
       datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 10, 15, 8, 34, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000)),
       datetime.datetime(2021, 3, 9, 8, 15, 22, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -21600))
```

Then, this:

```
import datetime
df['elapsed_time'] = (df['closed_time] - df['opened_time]).dt.total_seconds() / 3600
```

Results in a type error:

```
TypeError:  Timestamp subtraction must have the same timezones or no timezones
```

What is the recommended way to convert timezone-aware datetime objects (preferably by using the standard library in Python 3.7) to **US Eastern time** so that I can subtract the two columns and get an elapsed time?

Thanks!

Comment: You may wanna take a look at [pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html)

Comment: Is this what you're suggesting, @Ralubrusto?  `df['opened_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['opened_time'], utc=True).dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')`

Comment: While you're *working* with the data, use UTC (efficient, no ambiguities due to DST etc.). If you want some "human-readable" output, tz_convert to US/Eastern (or whatever you need).